# Fast drawing lots of rectangles one at a time in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

My application is fed data from an external device. After each data point, there is a short electronic 
dead time (of about 10µs) in which no other data point can arrive, which my application should use to process and display 
the data on screen in a scatter plot. My most important goal is to not exceed this electronic dead time. 
How would one approach this problem in a WPF based application, and what would be a way to benchmark different methods?

Things I've tried are:

- Creating a `Rectangle` in a `Canvas` for every arriving data point. This is too slow by a factor of 10.
- The same approach, but drawing `DrawingVisuals` in a custom control. Better, but still a little too slow. Adding visual/logical children to the tree may have too much overhead.
- A `UserControl` where all data points are stored in an array and displayed in the `OnRender` method. Here I have to draw every point again on each call to OnRender. This method therefore slows down over time, which is undesireable. Is there a way to tell `OnRender` not to clear the screen on each pass, so that I could paint incrementally?
- Displaying each point as a pixel in a `WriteableBitmap`. This seems to work, but I 've not found a way to determine, if invalidating part of the Bitmap does not add a few very long  wait times ocassionally (when the Image is actually refreshed on screen). Any Ideas for measuring this?

**Edit:**

In the comments, the point of buffering data and displaying it at a slower rate has been raised. 
The problem with that approach is, that at some point I have to process the buffer. 
Doing that during the measurement introduces a long time during which my system is busy and new events would be discarded. 
Therefore dealing with every point individually, but for good, would be more desireable. Using 10 µs to trigger the display for every event is much better than storing it into a buffer in no time and use 100µs every 50  ms or so to process the accumulated events.

I the olden (i.e. non-WPF) days, you could e.g. put the neccesary data into the graphics memory, and have the graphics card deal with it at its convenience. Of cource, it would not actually be displayed at a rate faster than 60Hz, but you did not have to touch this data again.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific: what is "lots of"? And is a pixel really a suitable "rectangle" for you? thanks

Comment: @Simon: Sure! I expect maybe 10.000 to 100.000 data points per second. One measurement does not exceed a few seconds. Pixels are rectangular enough for me =)

Comment: @Jens Regarding your update, I suggested using a second thread to transfer the buffer data to the WritableBitmap to solve exactly the problem you describe.

Comment: @chibacity: WriteableBitmap is a DispatcherObject and cannot be modified from threads other than the one that created it. Besides, I cannot guarantee that the process is running on a multicore CPU, so additional threads would not solve the problem.

Comment: @Jens I understand the ins and outs of dispatching in WPF. I assumed that you could receive data from your device on a non-UI thread. If you cannot guarantee a multi-proc\core machine, perhaps performance is going to be an even bigger issue. That's going to be a pretty old machine.

Comment: @Jens It would be useful if you could supply your code.

Comment: @chibacity: I can't, sorry. This is work. The machine is not old, but its an embedded device. The existing software works within my parameters, but uses GDI+ or something else low-level. I'd like to know if WPF is a suitable UI framework for this task. Maybe it simply isn't. =/

Comment: @Jens There may be an issue with how you are using the WritableBitmap. Without seeing at least some skeleton code, it's impossible to tell. Also is the device data generated on a non-UI thread?

Comment: @Jens Are you calling WritePixels or accessing the BackBuffer directly?

Comment: @chibacity: I used the Backbuffer directly. This had the fortunate advantage of being easy to convert to InteropBitmap, which seems to be faster by a factor of 2. I think using that might work, I'll have to do some more measurements. InteropBitmap (or even WriteableBitmap) is not very WPFish, but well. =)

Comment: @Jens I see a common journey in your original question: canvas -> DrawingVisual -> OnRender -> WritableBitmap. At each level you lose "WPF-ishness".

Comment: @Jens Also what version of .Net are you using? There were performance improvements to WritableBitmap in 4.0.

Comment: @chibacity: I am using 4.0. Thanks for all your effort!

Comment: @Jens NP. Presumably you have tried doing this without using Lock\Unlock, as that will eat a lot of the performance if you're updating 100k times per second.

Comment: @Jens 100k lock\unlocks takes ~275ms on my (high-powered) machine. This will obviously kill performance, hence my suggestion to have courser-grained updates. You could of course not lock at all and see how you get on. :)

Comment: @Jens Bump - are you calling lock\unlock for each of your 100k updates/second?

Comment: @chibacity: I was, yeah. Its required to call AddDirtyRect. Without lock/unlock it is indeed faster, that may be an option. (I still have to do it sometimes, otherwise the bitmap will not get updated, but that's not going to be a problem, since its fast enough).

Comment: @Jens I guess this is what I have been driving at when I say an update and not being to sustain that may per second. When I say update I mean lock -> update -> unlock. Lock\unlock is very expensive. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using a [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx) will be the fastest approach. For testing you could pre-allocate an array and use a Stopwatch to sample timings as you go about rendering, you can then analyse the timings to get some idea of performance.

One overriding issue you have is with garbage collection. This will unfortunately introduce potential for the exact kind of performance issues you describe i.e. occasional stalling whilst GC is carried out. You could experiment with low latency GC to mitigate this.

**Update**

Here is an example of using low latency GC:

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2008/08/10/low-latency-gc-in-net-3-5.aspx

You could leverage this to ensure that there are no garbage collections during your "dead time" i.e. rendering time.

**Update 2**

As I mentioned in my comment a while ago - are you batching updates to your WritableBitmap?

Your device update frequency is too high to able to sustain writing to the bitmap for each device update - I think there are 10k-100k updates per second. Try and update your bitmap on a more sensible frequency (e.g. 60 or 25 times per second), as the overhead of forcing a bitmap render will dominate performance at 10k-100k updates per second. Write to a buffer when you receive device updates, then periodically transfer this buffer to the WritableBitmap. You could use a timer for this, or do it every n device updates. In this way you will batch your updates and vastly reduce WritableBitmap render overhead.

**Update 3**

Ok, it sounds like you are updating the WritableBitmap 10k-100k times per second - this isn't feasible. Please try a frame\batch based mechanism as described previously. Also your display is only likely to be updated at 60 frames per second.

If you are concerned about blocking your device updates, then consider using two alternating back buffers and multi-threading. In this way you periodically switch which back buffer your device writes to, and use a second thread to render the swapped buffer to the WritableBitmap. As long as you can swap the buffer in < 10µs, you can do this in the dead time without blocking your device updates.

**Update 4**

Further to a response to my question, it would appear that there is currently a "lock\unlock" being called for each of the 100k updates per second. This is what is likely killing performance. On my (high-powered) system I measured 100k "lock\unlock" at ~275ms. That's pretty heavy and will be much worse on a lower powered system.

This is why I think 100k updates per second is not achievable i.e. lock -> update -> unlock. The locking is just too expensive.

You need to find a way of bringing the number of locking calls down by either not locking at all, locking every n operations, or perhaps batching requests and then applying the batched update in a lock. There's a few options here.

If you go for a batched update, it could be as small as 10 cycles, which would bring your update frequency down to 10k updates per second. This would reduce your locking overhead by a factor of 10.

Example benchmark code for locking overhead on 100k calls:

```
lock/unlock - Interval:1 - :289.47ms
lock/unlock - Interval:1 - :287.43ms
lock/unlock - Interval:1 - :288.74ms
lock/unlock - Interval:1 - :286.48ms
lock/unlock - Interval:1 - :286.36ms
lock/unlock - Interval:10 - :29.12ms
lock/unlock - Interval:10 - :29.01ms
lock/unlock - Interval:10 - :28.80ms
lock/unlock - Interval:10 - :29.35ms
lock/unlock - Interval:10 - :29.00ms
```

Code:

```
public void MeasureLockUnlockOverhead()
{
    const int TestIterations = 5;

    Action<string, Func<double>> test = (name, action) =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < TestIterations; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1:F2}ms", name, action());
        }
    };

    Action<int> lockUnlock = interval =>
    {
        WriteableBitmap bitmap =
           new WriteableBitmap(100, 100, 96d, 96d, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null);

        int counter = 0;

        Action t1 = () =>
        {
            if (++counter % interval == 0)
            {
                bitmap.Lock();
                bitmap.Unlock();
            }
        };

        string title = string.Format("lock/unlock - Interval:{0} -", interval);

        test(title, () => TimeTest(t1));
    };

    lockUnlock(1);
    lockUnlock(10);
}

[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Reliability",
    "CA2001:AvoidCallingProblematicMethods", MessageId = "System.GC.Collect")]
private static double TimeTest(Action action)
{
    const int Iterations = 100 * 1000;

    Action gc = () =>
    {
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();
    };

    Action empty = () => { };

    Stopwatch stopwatch1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    for (int j = 0; j < Iterations; j++)
    {
        empty();
    }

    double loopElapsed = stopwatch1.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;

    gc();

    action(); //JIT
    action(); //Optimize

    Stopwatch stopwatch2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    for (int j = 0; j < Iterations; j++)
    {
        action();
    }

    gc();

    double testElapsed = stopwatch2.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;

    return (testElapsed - loopElapsed);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into the low latency GC for sure!

Comment: @Jens Let me know how you get on, I'm interested to see how you get on with your real-time requirements. You may have to use to other optimization techniques such as writing to a back-buffer and then transferring to the bitmap periodically to get the perf you require - 10µs is pretty minimal!

Comment: Funnyly, setting the GC to LowLatency somewhat hurts the measured performance in some settings, and does not help in others. WriteableBitmap seems (barely) fast enough. I'll start a small bounty to see if there are more ideas.

Comment: Are you batching your bitmap updates as I suggested in my previous comment, or are you updating the bitmap as you receive device updates? Your updates are too frequent to sustain a one-to-one mapping.

Comment: @chibacity: I am not, no. I'd really like to avoid that, since my main focus is not exceeding a certain time limit for **every** operation. Doing a batch update 60 times a second would break that time limit 60 times per second, which is undesireable.

Comment: @Jens it is not feasible to update the bitmap 10k-100k per second as there is too much overhead associated with each update. Also, the display is unlikely to be updated more than 60 times per second anyway.

Comment: @Jens I'm not sure I follow re. breaking the time limit 60 times per second. The display will not update more than 60 times per second anyway, trying to update the bitmap 10k-100k times per second just isn't going to work.

Comment: Why do you want to update the bitmap with so high a frequency? - the user/you can't percieve it anyway. I would do as you do in a computer game - make a fixed loop - like the 60 times per second - where you update your bitmap and draw it. It is ofcourse another matter if the idea is to record the whole thing and play it back/analyse it later in slowmotion :)

Comment: I would use thread to do the polling of your data nice an easy and put it in a buffer that I can choose to read and flush in my loop - and I would'n try to draw anything in sync with the arrival of points.

Comment: @Rune I'm not sure about your point in polling as I don't think the OP wants to lose data - he needs to record, not sample. It is quite feasible to receive data and buffer it. I agree re. not trying to render on arrival of data - that's the point I'm making.

Comment: @Rune, chibacity: Thanks for your input. I've edited my original question. Hopefully my requirements are more understandable now.

Comment: @Jens Regarding your update, I suggested using a second thread to transfer the buffer data to the WritableBitmap to solve exactly the problem you describe. You collect data on one thread, and render it on another. This can be done concurrently. You only need to worry about synchronization and being able to swap the buffers over quickly. I think this is quite feasible.

Answer (score 2):

WPF relies on a retained composition engine which is cool, but it looks like you're more after a "simple" and raw bitmap display.

I think you have a good example of what you want to do here: https://web.archive.org/web/20140519134127/http://khason.net/blog/how-to-high-performance-graphics-in-wpf/

Answer (score 2):

**Full Disclosure: I have contributed to the WriteableBitmapEx open source project, however it is not my library nor am I affiliated with its owner**

To add to the excellent answer by [chibacity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/189516/chibacity), I would suggest looking at the [WriteableBitmapEx](http://WriteableBitmapEx.codeplex.com) library. This is an excellent WPF, Silverlight and Windows Phone library which adds GDI-like drawing extension methods (blitting, lines, shapes, transforms as well as batch operations) to the `WriteableBitmap` class.

The latest version of WBEx contains a refactor that I carried out to allow batch operations. The `WriteableBitmapEx` library now has an extension method called `GetBitmapContext()`, to return an `IDisposable` struct which wraps a single lock/unlock/invalidate block. With the following syntax you can easily batch your drawing calls and perform only one Lock/Unlock/Invalidate at the end

```
// Constructor of BitmapContext locks the bmp and gets a pointer to bitmap
using (var bitmapContext = writeableBitmap.GetBitmapContext())
{
     // Perform multiple drawing calls (pseudocode)
     writebleBitmap.DrawLine(...)
     writebleBitmap.DrawRectangle(...) 
     // etc ...
} // On dispose of bitmapcontext, it unlocks and invalidates the bmp
```

Answer (score 1):

If I get it right you have a scenario where you want to get data from your sensor for a few seconds - and show it. You have a realtime requirement - or do you store the data from your special "camera" as an image and the realtime plotting is just for shows?

If so you could wait the few seconds and then show the result?

It sounds like WritableBitmap could be a way to solve your problem.
I would assume that there is an overhead each time you have a lock/unlock block since it has to do with theading - so I don't think it is a good idea for each point.
To get timing on it you could use a profiler on a test project / test data - dotTrace from jetbrains is ok - I think they have a trial version.  You could also use a performance counter - that might be usefull for other stuff as well.

I would make it multithreaded and have a high priority thread to process the incomming points - or do you recive interrups from your device? As i understand it is more important to get all point than to draw all points rightaway.

You write that WritableBitmap is barely fast enough - so with your current solution I would try saving calls to AddDirtyRect so it is only at every n points/millisec - transfer to the frontbuffer should be fast even if it is a large block. 
You should be able to get it just as fast with wpf as with forms - its just nicer.

With some code and more info on your system it would be easier to answer :)