# WPF Efficiently update the height of array of Rectangles 31 times a second

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, drawrectangle

I'm working on a spectrum analyzer in WPF. The bars are Rectangles contained in a Grid. There are 128 bars and they are updated about 31 times a second. The program does what it is supposed to do, the only problem is that it seems to be very CPU heavy.

While the program was running, the CPU was at ~30%, and when I removed the code that updates the height of the bars to make sure that it was the culprit, the CPU went down to 0-5%.

I've tried overriding OnRender in a Grid, drawing the rectangles using DrawingContext.DrawRectangle() and invalidating the grid in a timer, but it wasn't any better.

Is there a better way to render the bars of a spectrum analyzer in WPF?

Comment: Have you seen this question? Are you using `WritableBitmap` or just plain `Rectangle` objects?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447794/fast-drawing-lots-of-rectangles-one-at-a-time-in-wpf

Comment: I am using `Rectangle` objects. I will look into that question, I don't have much experience with WriteableBitmaps.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is the issue, you should opt for D3DImage which allows to host DirectX scene in it. Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/walkthrough-hosting-direct3d9-content-in-wpf) out.